# How to Insert Data into Parse?

Tags: database, heroku, parse-platform

I have been following a class and it uses Heroku apps with Parse API to insert data into the database. In the video, the instructor's code works fine, while I keep getting "Save Failed" and no data in the database when I double-check. Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


public class StarterApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId("sdfsdkf34390")
            .clientKey(null)
            .server("http://instagramtrynumber3.herokuapp.com/parse")
    .build()
    );

    ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
    gameScore.put("score", 1337);
    gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
    gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
    gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
      public void done(ParseException e) {
          if (e == null) {
              Log.i("Parse", "Save Succeeded");
          } else {
              Log.i("Parse", "Save Failed");
          }
      }
  });


  ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
  ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
  // Optionally enable public read access.
  // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
  ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay...I have found an answer, finally. While it may seem trivial and silly that it works (it does to me), when filling in the `.server` part, make sure there is a "/" at the end of your URL, such as: `.server(http://instagramtrynumber3.herokuapp.com/parse/`.